# Size of localStorage in node.js?

Tags: node.js

What is the size of localStorage in node.js ?

I have used localStorage on browser side , it has a a limit of around 5 MB, but i do not know what is the size limit of localStorage in node.js ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `localStorage` in node.js, that's purely a browser-side thing. If you need persistent storage, you should look into using a database module or key-value store of some kind.

Comment: i have used localStorage in node.js , it is present in there. If there is no localStorage then how we use modules like https://www.npmjs.org/package/localStorage

Comment: What I meant is that there is no `localStorage` provided by node.js core. If you want to have the same API available, you will need to use a third party module to add such functionality (such as the module you mentioned).

Comment: That would depend on the third party module's implementation.